# Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

my code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/webdriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

When I run the program, the browser opens for half a second then closes down and gives the error
 `Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85`

I'm using this version of chromedriver  for my program: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.38/
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: update your chrome

Comment: My chrome version is `84.0.4147.125 ` which is up to date.

Comment: use this chromedriver https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/

Comment: But your Chromedriver is for Chrome 85...

Comment: I get the same exact error when using version 84, `Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
`

Comment: you need to check your browser version before chose chrome driver refer this article follow this link to learn about initiating selenium chrome driver https://techbitezzz.blogspot.com/2020/08/selenium-tutorials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using the latest *chrome=84.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v84.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 84**

- Possibly you have downloaded [*chromedriver=85.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.38/)
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=85.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 85**

So there is a clear mismatch between *Chrome Browser v84.0* and *ChromeDriver 85.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser are updating time to time so you need to use exact driver exe according to your browser version please check your browser version and download driver exe based to match to your browser version in https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and set path and refresh project and rerun

Comment: I've re-created the project and I still got the same error, using version 84.

Comment: what is your web browser version? did you set up path properly ?

Comment: My Chrome version is 84.0.4147.125 and my chromedriver is 84.0.4147.30

Comment: driver.get('http://google.com/')    
insted of this single quotation use below double quotation 
driver.get("http://google.com/")

Answer (score -2):

```
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

insted of this single quotation use below double quotation

```
driver.get("http://google.com/")
```